# Failing to successfully implement a left join - columns remain null

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm working with some price data and I have two databases. In one, I have daily prices and on the other I have quarterly fundamental data. 
However , stocks in each database have different identifiers so I got a linking table . I want to join my price database with the linking table so I get the matching identifier for each stock . The final goal is to then join this modified price table with the fundamental data table ( I'll make a join on the identifier I got from the linking table).

However , the columns I want to fill : Dados_CRSP.GVKEY , LINKDATE AND LINKENDDATE are returned null. It seems no modifications are made to the price table. This is the first time I am working with SQL so I'm probably doing something really stupid!
Also , sorry for the bad formatting.

The code and an example of the data follow below :

Dados CRSP (price table) :

```
+--------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
| RET_DATE     | PERMCO |  PRICE  | GVKEY | LINKDATE | LINKENDDATE |
+--------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
| '1986-02-04' |   7976 | -17.625 | NULL  | NULL     | NULL        |
| '1986-02-05' |   7976 | -18.375 | NULL  | NULL     | NULL        |
+--------------+--------+---------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

LINKTABLE :

```
+-------+--------+--------------+--------------+
| gvkey | PERMCO |    LINKDT    |  LINKENDDT   |
+-------+--------+--------------+--------------+
|  1004 |  20000 | '1972-04-24' | '2014-12-31' |
|  1010 |  22156 | 1962-01-31', | '1984-06-28' |
+-------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

CODE :

```
CREATE TABLE Dados_CRSP
(
RET_DATE DATE, -- date
PERMCO INTEGER, -- price identifier
PRICE FLOAT,
GVKEY integer , -- This starts empty
LINKDATE DATE , -- This starts empty
LINKENDDATE DATE -- This starts empty
)
;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE filename
INTO TABLE Dados_CRSP 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES;

CREATE TABLE LINK_TABLE
(
GVKEY INTEGER, -- fundamental data identifier
PERMCO INTEGER,
LINKDATE DATE, -- Date when GVKEY PERMCO mapping starts for given stock
LINKENDDATE DATE -- Date when GVKEY PERMCO mapping end for given stock
)
;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE filename
INTO TABLE LINK_TABLE
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES;

UPDATE LINK_TABLE
SET LINKENDDATE = '2014-12-31'
WHERE LINKENDDATE = '0000-00-00';

--Added indexes to make the join faster
ALTER TABLE LINK_TABLE ADD INDEX (PERMCO);
ALTER TABLE LINK_TABLE ADD INDEX (LINKDATE);
ALTER TABLE LINK_TABLE ADD INDEX (LINKENDDATE); 

ALTER TABLE Dados_CRSP ADD INDEX (PERMCO);
ALTER TABLE Dados_CRSP ADD INDEX (RET_DATE);


--I make the join on matching identifiers and when the date is between the date of 
--activity for the given identifier. I do this because the  same company may change mapping through time`
UPDATE Dados_CRSP 
LEFT JOIN LINK_TABLE ON 
    Dados_CRSP.PERMCO = LINK_TABLE.PERMCO
SET 
    Dados_CRSP.GVKEY = LINK_TABLE.GVKEY 
    AND Dados_CRSP.LINKDATE = LINK_TABLE.LINKDATE 
    AND Dados_CRSP.LINKENDDATE = LINK_TABLE.LINKENDDATE
WHERE 
    Dados_CRSP.RET_DATE >= LINK_TABLE.LINKDATE
    AND Dados_CRSP.RET_DATE <= LINK_TABLE.LINKENDDATE;
```

Comment: The dates in two tables seem to be in different format.

Comment: That's just a display thing. The columns are both type `DATE` as shown in the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: @EdGibbs exactly, it was my bad. I copied one table from the CSV and other from MySQL so the display was different. It is now corrected.

Comment: Are you sure? This line seems odd to me: WHERE LINKENDDATE = 'E';

Comment: @Tim3880 My bad on that part of the code , it actually is WHERE LINKENDDATE = '0000-00-00'; When I display the table's properties in MySQL both columns are in the DATE format.

Answer (score 1):

Your WHERE clause doesn't handle NULLs, so it's creating an implicit inner join.  Also, you're UPDATE syntax is just wrong.  The list of columns after SET is separated by commas, not ANDs.

You'll need to do the following:

```
UPDATE Dados_CRSP 
LEFT JOIN LINK_TABLE ON 
    Dados_CRSP.PERMCO = LINK_TABLE.PERMCO
SET 
    Dados_CRSP.GVKEY = LINK_TABLE.GVKEY,
    Dados_CRSP.LINKDATE = LINK_TABLE.LINKDATE,
    Dados_CRSP.LINKENDDATE = LINK_TABLE.LINKENDDATE
WHERE 
    (Dados_CRSP.RET_DATE >= LINK_TABLE.LINKDATE OR LINK_TABLE.LINKDATE IS NULL
    AND (Dados_CRSP.RET_DATE <= LINK_TABLE.LINKENDDATE OR LINK_TABLE.LINKENDDATE IS NULL);
```

Alternately, you could just specify this condition as a JOIN condition.  You don't need to handle NULLs there because, well, the JOIN hasn't happened yet.

```
UPDATE Dados_CRSP 
LEFT JOIN LINK_TABLE ON 
    Dados_CRSP.PERMCO = LINK_TABLE.PERMCO
    AND Dados_CRSP.RET_DATE >= LINK_TABLE.LINKDATE
    AND Dados_CRSP.RET_DATE <= LINK_TABLE.LINKENDDATE
SET 
    Dados_CRSP.GVKEY = LINK_TABLE.GVKEY,
    Dados_CRSP.LINKDATE = LINK_TABLE.LINKDATE,
    Dados_CRSP.LINKENDDATE = LINK_TABLE.LINKENDDATE;
```

That's the only actual design issue I see, but that's assuming you actually do want a LEFT JOIN here.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't work. Nulls are still returned for every row.

Comment: @ArturSilva Then take a look at your data.  I mean, does `SELECT * FROM Dados_CRSP LEFT JOIN LINK_TABLE ON Dados_CRSP.PERMCO = LINK_TABLE.PERMCO` give you all nulls for the LINK_TABLE fields?  Are you sure your data joins at all?  Your example data certainly doesn't.

Comment: the query above returns no nulls. I've also manually searched the data and the data certainly joins.

Comment: I got it to work by removing Dados_CRSP.LINKDATE and Dados_CRSP.LINKENDDATE from the set clause. I didn't need them so I tried it and for some reason it worked, but no idea why. Thanks for the help @BaconBits.